# Small sample linear regression: Where to start

Tags: regression, self-study, methodology

FULL DISCLOSURE: This is homework.

I have been provided with a small data set (n=21) the data are messy, looking at it in a scatterplot matrix provides me with little to no insight. I've been provided with 8 variables that are metrics created from a longditudinal study (BI, CONS, CL, CR, ..., VOBI). The other measurements are of mutual fund sales, returns, asset levels, market share, share of sales, and proportion of sales to assets

[image]

Correlations, are everywhere.

```
               BI       CONS           CL          CR         QT        COM        CONV        VOBI          s            r           a          ms         ss       share      share2
BI      1.0000000  0.7620445  0.639830594  0.70384322  0.7741463  0.8451500  0.84704440  0.85003686  0.2106773 -0.238431047  0.36184548  0.40007830  0.4076563  0.31643802 -0.28283564
CONS    0.7620445  1.0000000  0.933595967  0.96979599  0.9892533  0.9069803  0.96781703  0.93416972  0.2316209 -0.074351798  0.31952292  0.40259511  0.4442877  0.24783884 -0.14788906
CL      0.6398306  0.9335960  1.000000000  0.88297431  0.8993748  0.8133169  0.89922684  0.81132166  0.1200420 -0.001107093  0.22132116  0.26729067  0.3033221  0.07650924 -0.25595278
CR      0.7038432  0.9697960  0.882974312  1.00000000  0.9788150  0.8965754  0.92335363  0.90848199  0.2934774 -0.119340914  0.35973640  0.46409570  0.5012178  0.32832247 -0.09005985
QT      0.7741463  0.9892533  0.899374782  0.97881497  1.0000000  0.9216887  0.95458369  0.94848419  0.2826278 -0.108430256  0.35520090  0.43290221  0.4823314  0.31761015 -0.12903075
COM     0.8451500  0.9069803  0.813316918  0.89657544  0.9216887  1.0000000  0.90302002  0.89682825  0.4305866 -0.255581594  0.50724121  0.55718441  0.5773171  0.40378679 -0.12085524
CONV    0.8470444  0.9678170  0.899226843  0.92335363  0.9545837  0.9030200  1.00000000  0.96097892  0.1993837 -0.065237725  0.32010735  0.41843335  0.4531298  0.28873934 -0.19668858
VOBI    0.8500369  0.9341697  0.811321664  0.90848199  0.9484842  0.8968283  0.96097892  1.00000000  0.2424889 -0.087126942  0.30390489  0.40390750  0.4845432  0.36588655 -0.07137107
s       0.2106773  0.2316209  0.120041993  0.29347742  0.2826278  0.4305866  0.19938371  0.24248894  1.0000000 -0.173034217  0.91766914  0.84673519  0.8596887  0.61299987  0.32072790
r      -0.2384310 -0.0743518 -0.001107093 -0.11934091 -0.1084303 -0.2555816 -0.06523773 -0.08712694 -0.1730342  1.000000000 -0.22512978 -0.18337773 -0.1030943 -0.17650579  0.51768144
a       0.3618455  0.3195229  0.221321163  0.35973640  0.3552009  0.5072412  0.32010735  0.30390489  0.9176691 -0.225129778  1.00000000  0.92445370  0.8656139  0.63049461  0.03876774
ms      0.4000783  0.4025951  0.267290668  0.46409570  0.4329022  0.5571844  0.41843335  0.40390750  0.8467352 -0.183377734  0.92445370  1.00000000  0.9572730  0.77582501  0.08435813
ss      0.4076563  0.4442877  0.303322147  0.50121775  0.4823314  0.5773171  0.45312978  0.48454322  0.8596887 -0.103094325  0.86561394  0.95727301  1.0000000  0.83931302  0.24371447
share   0.3164380  0.2478388  0.076509240  0.32832247  0.3176102  0.4037868  0.28873934  0.36588655  0.6129999 -0.176505786  0.63049461  0.77582501  0.8393130  1.00000000  0.20313930
share2 -0.2828356 -0.1478891 -0.255952782 -0.09005985 -0.1290307 -0.1208552 -0.19668858 -0.07137107  0.3207279  0.517681444  0.03876774  0.08435813  0.2437145  0.20313930  1.00000000
```

Now, I've tried running a number of "tests", for example:

```
summary.lm(share2 ~ BI + ...)
```

However, none of them provide any reasonable result (mostly negative adjusted R^2).

I'm wondering, if you had data where it looked like there was no relationships (linear at least).

What would your next steps be?

P.S: I did try a number of model formulas that contained interaction effects and received much better results (R^2 Ra^2 > 80% and significant f-tests) but not all the interaction effects where significant.

Comment: What is the aim of your analyses?

Comment: Yes, I did leave that out, didn't I. The goal is to find a predictive equation for share2 from the variables provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd probably take a look at a ridge regression or, better, the lasso. These techniques are often used when there is multicollinearity. There are several options for doing this in R: See the Regularized and Shrinkage Methods section of the [Machine Learning & Statistical Learning](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html) Task View on CRAN.

You don't have enough data to start thinking about some of the techniques listed in other sections of that Task View.

Comment: With 21 subjects and 8 variables, and without any stated question, hypothesis or model .... what question would ridge regression answer?

Comment: @Harvey - Brandon stated in a comment to his Q that he wanted a model for prediction purposes.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that the only thing worth doing here is testing a very focussed hypothesis, if you have one. But it seems like you don't.

With so few cases and so many variables, anything else would (in my opinion) be a fishing expedition. That could be a bit useful, perhaps, to generate an hypothesis to test with new data. But any results from a multivariate unfocussed analysis of these data is likely to be a false positive coincidental finding that probably won't hold up with new data.

Answer (score 5):

I find @ucfagls's idea most appropriate here, since you have very few observations and a lot of variables. Ridge regression should do its job for prediction purpose.

Another way to analyse the data would be to rely on [PLS regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_least_squares_regression) (in this case, PLS1), which bears some idea with regression on PCA scores but seems more interesting in your case. As multicollinearity might be an issue there, you can look at *sparse* solution (see e.g., the [spls](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spls/index.html) or the [mixOmics](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixOmics/index.html) R packages).

Answer (score 2):

If you're frustrated with too many correlations, and since you already have your covariance matrix (well almost) you could do a principal components analysis. You'll end up with fewer dimensions, which is probably fine considering your data set size, and what you end up with won't be intercorrelated anymore.

Comment: Hrmmm, prcomp returns ridiculous results. PC1 accounts for 100% of variance with a SD of 20800! No rotation mind you. Let me try that again

Comment: Eh? PCA **is** a rotation.

Comment: A problem with PCA is interpretation the final model. Say PC1 and PC2 are significant terms in the model. To explain the relationship between share2 and the original data to gain understanding on it, you need to pick apart the loadings of the variables on PC1 and PC2. This likely won't matter too much is prediction is all Brandon is interested in though.

Comment: Can't edit that comment now, but I meant scale, not rotation.

Comment: @Brandon - so that was going to be my other comment on the PCA you did - I think you should standardise (`scale = TRUE`) if the variables are in different units or take different ranges.